# Excel VBA Delete Row If Misspelled Word

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete the entire row, if a cell contains a misspelled word. If a row is removed, is skips a row, thus missing any misspelled words that may occur directly after another.

Here is the code:

```
Sub DeleteMispelledCells()
For Each cl In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
If Not Application.CheckSpelling(Word:=cl.Text) Then _
cl.EntireRow.Delete
Next cl
End Sub
```

I understand the issue is the cl is not taking into account that the current row was removed, but I do not know how to correct this. I am also aware that if the loop ran from the last row to the first, instead of the first to the last, that it would also be corrected. However, I do not know how to do this either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to loop through every row in reverse order you'll do something like this:

```
Sub DeleteMispelledCells()
  Dim lRow As Long, cl As Range

  With ActiveSheet
    For lRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
      For Each cl In .Rows(lRow)
        If Not IsEmpty(cl) Then
          If Not Application.CheckSpelling(Word:=cl.Text) Then
            cl.EntireRow.Delete
            Exit For
          End If
        End If
      Next cl
    Next lRow
  End With
End Sub
```

I am not 100 % sure I've gotten all of the syntax right, as I am not on a computer at which I can test it, but it should at least give you somewhere to start.

Comment: `For Each cl In .Row(lRow)` should be `For Each cl In .Rows(lRow)` and it runs fine on my machine.  The difference is `.Row` versus `.Rows`.

Comment: @JoshuaRoss Thanks for testing, fixed now.

Comment: No problem, I considered just editing for you but you have to change more than 1 character ^_^

Comment: @eirikdaude I thought this did it, but I am getting the following error "Invalid use of Null" for the following line of code

`If Not Application.CheckSpelling(Word:=cl.Text) Then`

Comment: I would assume that it is because it is checking the spelling in a cell which doesn't contain a value, I am not absolutely certain how `UsedRange` is defined, but switching `For Each cl In .Rows(lRow)` to `For Each cl In Intersect(.Rows(lRow), .UsedRange)` might work, alternately you could add another `If`-statement outside the one you refer to in your comment, checking if the cell is blank. Updated the answer with an example of how to do the latter. @FredJLangemarkIII

Comment: You are a genius @eirikdaude, you nailed it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

This is a *classic* problem in this kind of loop-controlled logic (in any programming language).  If you are iterating through, say, 5 rows ("#1..5"), and you delete the first row, then ... there are now 4 rows and what used to be row #2 is now row #1 and what used to be row #3 is now #2.  So, the loop proceeds to "row #2" and guess what:  you just skipped over "the *former* row #2," now in position #1.

Looping through the list backwards, as shown earlier, is one good way to compensate.

Another way, and one that I personally prefer, is to *first* loop through the items, *flagging* the ones that you decide you want to delete (e.g. by setting a flag-value in another column). *Then,* in a separate (backwards) loop, actually delete the flagged items.  This will make it a lot easier for you to properly *debug* the logic that checks for those misepeled wurds.  ;-)  First decide what you want to do, then go back and do it.