# Copy misspelled word(s) to adjacent column(s)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of keywords in a single column. I need to insert any misspelled words to the adjacent cell for a manual review. Only misspelled words, not the entire cell.

This VBA script gets me most of the way there but I can't figure out how to copy the misspelled words. Also the Offset(0,1) errors out, but Offset(1,0) works. WTH?

Right now I'd be happy with just the first misspelled word being copied but if it can loop through and insert them all to the cells to the right of them then that is wonderful.

Using the VBA code from [Excel VBA Delete Row If Mispelled Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756687/excel-vba-delete-row-if-mispelled-word)

```
Sub DeleteMispelledCells()
Dim lRow As Long, cl As Range

With ActiveSheet
For lRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
  For Each cl In .Rows(lRow)
    If Not IsEmpty(cl) Then
      If Not Application.CheckSpelling(Word:=cl.Text)
        cl.Copy
        cl.Offset(1, 0).Insert 'The Offset(0, 1) throws an error. Why?
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Exit For
      End If
    End If
  Next cl
Next lRow
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there more than one word per cell ??

Comment: This looks like Cargo Cult Programming ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming ). For example, you are asking about checking a single column but you are using code that refers to the entire used range. Also, you are looping backwards, which is somewhat pointless in this case since you aren't deleting. On a separate note -- do you really want to *insert* new cells? You can directly copy the value from one cell to another cell with no use of methods like `Copy` or `Paste` or `Insert` needed.

Comment: There is more than one word per cell, anywhere from 1 word to 20 max. 

The looping backwards was a functionality of the original code b/c it was deleting the entire row. I am 100% find with copy/pasting the misspelled word(s) into the Column B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this small *UDF()*:

```
Public Function CheckPhrase(r As Range) As String
   Dim MyText As String, ary, a
   MyText = LCase(r(1).Text)
   MyText = FixUp(MyText)
   ary = Split(MyText, " ")

   Dim oxlAp As Object
   Set oxlAp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

   CheckPhrase = ""
   For Each a In ary
      If Not oxlAp.CheckSpelling(a) Then
         CheckPhrase = CheckPhrase & vbCrLf & a
      End If
   Next a

   oxlAp.Quit
   Set oxlAp = Nothing
End Function



Public Function FixUp(sin As String) As String
   Dim t As String, ary, a
   t = sin
   ary = Array(",", ".", ";", ":""'")

   For Each a In ary
      t = Replace(t, a, "")
   Next a
   FixUp = t
End Function
```

For example:

[image]

***Note:***

Turn on text wrap in the cells containing the *UDF()*.

Comment: OMG it works! The only thing is that it is slamming multiple misspelled words together on the same line. Can it instead just leave a space between them? I am using Excel 2013.

Comment: Got it. Thanks :) Send me your paypal address and I'll buy you a beer!

CheckPhrase = CheckPhrase & " " & a

Comment: @ComputerGiant  Thanks for the feedback!